# Thread Scheduler Simulation: Correct Way to Wake Up and Sleep a Pthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, scheduling, condition-variable

I am trying to design my own thread scheduler using a First Come First Serve strategy, and I'm not sure whether the way I put threads to sleep and wake them up is the correct approach. I am using C++ and the Pthreads library.

My idea is this:

- Main thread instantiates a worker thread.
- Separate `schedule()` function gets called from a worker thread denoting that the calling thread should be scheduled. Passes in an `arrival time`, `id`, `remaining time`.
- Within `schedule()`, create my own `Thread` object which stores the `arrival time`, `id`, and `remaining time` attributes of a particular thread (these are attributes that I made up). The `Thread` object also has its own condition variable.
- Every time the `schedule()` function gets called, a `Thread` object will be created and added to the back of the queue.
- Once the `Thread` object has been added to the queue, the thread that called `schedule()` should wait on its corresponding condition variable.
- Then the condition variable of the `Thread` object at the front of the queue should be signaled, indicating that it should run. All other threads should wait on the condition variables in their respective `Thread` objects.

**Example**: 5 `Thread` objects exist in `queue[0]`, `queue[1]`, `queue[2]`, `queue[3]`, and `queue[4]`. The thread represented by `queue[0]` should be running, and the threads represented by `queue[1]`, `queue[2]`, `queue[3]`, and `queue[4]` should be waiting on their respective condition variables. Once queue[0] finishes executing, it will get removed from the queue, all the `Thread` objects will be moved forward, and the new `queue[0]` will be signaled to run. If I call `schedule()` from a new worker thread now, a new `Thread` object should be created and added at `queue[4]`. The calling thread should then wait on `queue[4]`.

To test out this design, I wrote an example. I omitted the `arrival time`, `id`, and `remaining time` fields because they are not important at this point. Here is the example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <pthread.h>
using namespace std;

class Thread {
    public:
            pthread_cond_t conVar;
};

vector<Thread> queue;
pthread_mutex_t lock;

void schedule() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    cout << "Thread 1 locks the mutex\n";
    queue.push_back(first);
    pthread_cond_wait(&(queue.back()).conVar,&lock);
}

void *worker(void *arg) {

    Thread first;
    cout << "Thread 1 adding to queue. Going for the wait...\n";

    schedule();

    cout << "Got out of the wait. Let's do some work\n";

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            cout << i << " ";

    cout << "\n";

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {


    vector<Thread> queue;
    pthread_t a;

    pthread_create(&a,NULL,worker,NULL);
    cout << "Sleeping in the main thread for a bit....\n";
    sleep(1);

    cout << "Now let's signal the Thread object in the queue\n";

    int result = pthread_mutex_trylock(&lock);
    if(result != 0)
            sleep(3);
    pthread_cond_signal(&(queue.front()).conVar);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    pthread_join(a,NULL);


    return 0;

}
```

I have tried this example code several times, and the main thread always executes first and tries to signal the front of the queue. The worker thread never gets the queue in time to insert the `Thread` object, and I keep getting a segfault because the main thread tries to signal a condition variable that doesn't exist.

**My question is this**: Is this design a valid way to put threads to sleep and wake them up as part of a scheduling algorithm? Or will the main thread always execute first and try to signal an empty queue?

Comment: I only see one Thread object and no schedule() method.  Be careful since Thread first is allocated on the stack of worker() and so will go out of scope when worker exits

Comment: @KC-NH yeah, worker should be a member function of Thread, the Thread instance should be dynamically-allocated with operator new, lots of stuff:)

Comment: You only have one lock.  Is that lock protecting the queue?   It's not going to work well to go into a wait state while holding a global lock.

Answer (score 0):

The 'main' thread is just a thread that happens to be created by the OS loader instead of by user code.  It is not 'special' in any way.

One problem is that you are trying to synchronize threads with sleep calls.  This will not end well.

If you want to try this, signal the other way first. Pass a condvar to the worker and wait on it in main.  When the worker has inserted itself into the queue, it can signal the condvar so that main can continue.